# Write new file without duplicate with r

Tags: r, file, readfile

I have read a txt file into an R data.frame. Some lines are duplicated. How can i write to a new file without a duplicate (only one of the duplicates for each duplicate)
 For example:

```
A; a
B; a
C; a
A; a
C; a
A; b
```

I must write to new file:

```
A; a
B; a
C; a
A; b
```

I tried. My code:

```
#read file 
t = read.table('/home/BigClaster.txt',sep=';',header = FALSE)
........
```

I have big file ~ 1269821 lines in txt file.
When i read file RStudio in Environment show me line size without duplicate (1,095,079) 
[image]

When i rewrite to new file i get duplicate lines

Comment: Try `df1[!duplicated(df1),]` or `unique(df)`

Answer (score 1):

**R base**

```
 t[!duplicated(t), ]
```

**Dplyr**

```
t %>% distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
```

**Result**

```
  V1 V2
1  A  a
2  B  a
3  C  a
6  A  b
```

Comment: when i tryed this code  t[!duplicated(t), ]  , i get many little lines of my data. My txt file is 1269821 lines. after t[!duplicated(t), ] i get 286,535 lines

Comment: @Dossan it only returns non duplicated.